# Work with File in windows

Tags: c++, windows, file

I need a function in c++ to check if a given path/filename exists on the computer.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: As in [C++: Which is the best method of checking for file existence on windows platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403986/c-which-is-the-best-method-of-checking-for-file-existence-on-windows-platform) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be another possibilty besides the ones from the comments
[PathFileExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: It doesn't work on my PC It show this error :                                 undefined reference to `_imp__PathFileExistsA@4'

Comment: read the documentation. you need to link against the "Shlwapi.lib" library